# System index is not being used when running a SOQL query with DAY_ONLY()

Tags: apex, soql, indexing

CreateDate is a system index field maintained by Salesforce. I'd like to know when you running a query like this:

```
 Select Id from Account Where Day_Only(CreatedDate) > exampleDate
```

Does the **Day_Only** function make the **query un-selective**? Is the **System index** used when using soql functions? Salesforce query plan says CreatedDate is indexed, but i'm not sure it is used when running the code.

I believe Salesforce does not use the index when you use Day_Only function with a **custom** index.

Comment: If you changed exampleDate to be a DateTime, then you wouldn't need to use the [`DAY_ONLY()` function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm#d16423e113) in the where clause.

Comment: Sure, this will solve the problem. What I really want to know is if the system index still be used with soql functions.

Comment: No, as per the answers, it won't in this case. The Query Plan tool is showing a full table scan. That basically means looking at ever record in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Analysis

Using Developer Console, you can gather the following evidence for yourself when you have this type of question. **Long story short, fields will not be optimized via index if they are wrapped in an expression.**

---

*The plot thickens*. You actually can get an index while using an expression if you use [Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm). The following queries do use an index:

```
SELECT Id FROM User WHERE DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) >= LAST_N_DAYS:42
SELECT Id FROM User WHERE DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) = THIS_YEAR
```

---

## Evidence

**Query:**

```
SELECT Id FROM User WHERE CreatedDate > 2016-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

**Leading Operation Type:**

> Index

**Notes:**

> None

[image: Datetime Query Plan]

---

**Query:**

```
SELECT Id FROM User WHERE DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) > 2016-01-01
```

**Leading Operation Type:**

> TableScan

**Notes:**

> Not considering filter for optimization because isExpression. Table: User Fields: ["CreatedDate"]

[image: DAY_ONLY Query Plan]

Comment: +1 I thought for sure CALENDAR_YEAR would have at least been optimized, because it would be a contiguous range in the index... but it's not. I've learned something new today.

Comment: Well, it does work with date literals. Which I think your answer really helps explain.

Comment: Thanks. The class is using Day_Only(CreatedDate) > exampleDate, I use DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) > LAST_N_DAYS:7 in the query plan. This is where my confusion from.